# Condition for a finitely generated flat module be projective

Tags: modules, projective-module, finitely-generated, flatness

Prove that:

Let $R$ be a commuatative ring, let $T$ be total quotient ring of $R$. A finitely generated flat $R$-module $M$ is projective if and only if the scalar extension $T\otimes_R M$ is a projective $T$-module.

Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

Forward direction is easy since taking total quotient is a localisation. For the reverse direction see Theorem 1 of the following paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1261060583